# An example of a set with empty interior but non-empty clousure's interior

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I'm triying to construct a bounded subset $A$ of $\mathbb{R}^2$ such that $int(A)=\emptyset$ but $int\left(\overline{A}\right)\ne \emptyset$ I can't see how to start, i've tried to use $A=\{(1/n,0):n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ it's interior is empty but also the clousure's interior. Any hint? Or generic example? I'm using the usual topology of the plane.

Comment: I know that example of rationals could work, but I don't know if the intersection with some bounded "ball" makes them work

Comment: Try the set of all points in the unit square with rational coordinates.

Comment: I'll try right now thanks!

Comment: "I know that example of rationals could work, but I don't know if the intersection with some bounded "ball" makes them work"  it would.  It absolutely would.  So *any* bounded set in R^2 intersected Ted with Q^2 ( or even just QxR) will do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In $\mathbb R$, one can consider $A:=\mathbb Q \cap [0,1]$, which has empty interior, but whose closure is all of $[0,1]$. Using this same example, we consider

$$A \times A \subseteq \mathbb R^2.$$

Since the usual topology is equivalent to the product topology (boxes), we know that the closure of $A \times A$ is the unit square, which has nonempty interior.